# helm-mode and minibuffer-complete-word

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, emacs-helm

I recently began to use `helm-mode` in Emacs. While I like the listing of possible file names matching whatever I typed in `find-file` or `write-file`, I really like to be able to use <kbd>SPC</kbd> key for the `minibuffer-complete-word` function. Many times files will be saved as `File1` / `File2` / etc. The `minibuffer-complete-word` function will then auto-complete all the way to `File` and give me the choice to type the number, which is really handy but can not be done with `helm-mode`.

I tried to add the following to my `init.el` file:

```
(add-hook 'helm-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    ;; (local-set-key (kdb "SPC") 'minibuffer-complete-word)
    (local-set-key "SPC" 'minibuffer-complete-word)))
```

It does not work, either with `SPC` or `(kdb "SPC")`. Would some guru show me the way to do it?

Comment: FYI, Helm has a mailing list for questions like this if you don't get an answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/emacs-helm